# Spring batch job application hangs with step partition

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

Our application is implemented using spring batch step partition with thread size 4. 
It means that our step which reads 8 Million records in 4 threads with each thread reads 2 million records. The threads are at some point of code basically last call in the application code waits for longer than expected about 40 min instead of 5 to 10 min.

out step configuration is like below(sample only). All 4 threads are started but some part of the method statements/lines (ex: println stmts) are not even executed though condition meets.

Have few questions below and need help if I have missed out anything in the step partition configuration.

1) Do I need explicitly mark the methods synchronized or we don't need?currently we just wrote java methods in Java class (state less ,i.e. no field values shared other than injected bean references in the class).

2) if i need to make all my business methods used in the spring batch has to synchronized for the step partition ,what is the best way.

```
<!-- partitioner job -->
  <job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

    <!-- master step, 10 threads (grid-size)  -->
    <step id="masterStep">
    <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
        <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
    </partition>
    </step>

  </job>

  <!-- each thread will run this job, with different stepExecutionContext values. -->
  <step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="pagingItemReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
            processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="1" />
    </tasklet>
  </step>

  <bean id="rangePartitioner" class="com.mkyong.partition.RangePartitioner" />

  <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

  <!-- inject stepExecutionContext -->
  <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.mkyong.processor.UserProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="threadName" value="#{stepExecutionContext[name]}" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: Can you add the configuration for your reader and writer please?

Comment: @MichaelMinella, Thanks for your reply. The readers and writers configurations are regular and no additional parameters. My only issue is do I need to make methods synchronized if I am using spring batch range partition which runs each step in parallel by using threads.

Comment: I application code is exactly the same way is explained at below link http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/

Comment: I'm asking about the readers and writers because I want to know if they are step scoped.  If they are (and probably should be for partitioning), you'd have an instance per partition.  If they are not, you'll run into issues.  Synchronizing them really defeats the purpose of going multithreading...

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMinella, it answered my question, readers and writers are step scoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved as per comments by @MichaelMinella. I don't have to have synchronized on methods for partitioning.

The reason for my batch was struck is because of stored procedure issue and not related to spring batch